# cant "read/locate" excel from <input type="file"> maatwebsite

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import to my DB using maatwebsite, when i change $excel to a real path, it is working. when $excel is in use, that error shows. how to solve this?.

error code
[image: error code]

home controller
[image: home controller]

programs blade
[image: programs blade]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your files don't have a file extension.

You can explicitly specify the file type like this:

```
Excel::import(new ProgramsImport, $excel, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
```

Answer (score 0):

found an answer here, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cant-upload-a-file-in-laravel-5,

I forgot to add it on the form. thanks.